# How I can make GUI of Netbeans look darker?

Tags: eclipse, gui, netbeans

I have sensitive eyes. It is important for me - having everything dark in my monitor. For example, [this is my Eclipse](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2448443/eclipse-black.png). How I can make Netbeans good for my eyes? I work under Linux, Lubuntu. Thank you very much for answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched for and used any of the many NetBeans dark/black themes I see are available?

Comment: I found only [grey Nimbus theme-plugin](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2448443/netbeans-nimbus-gray-look-and-feel.png). You know some black themes? This also look not bad, I can use it. [Link for plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46003).